# How to put subclassed view controller's view into super class baseviewcontroller's contentview?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I've created a super class `uiviewcontroller` class called `baseviewcontroller` to contain the basic UI most of my app screen will require. It includes a custom `navigation` bar and a "custom tab-bar" i've created in xib using `UIView` and `protocols` at the bottom of the view. So that in the future, i hope to just subclass this `baseviewcontroller` to include all of its basic `UI` elements. I can subclass this `baseviewcontroller` no problem, but the new `uiviewcontroller's` ui element at the bottom will be covered by the "tab-bar" i've created.

I tried to add a new `UIView` called content view in the `baseviewcontroller`, set up its constraint in relation to the "tab-bar" and in subsequent view controller try to add their view into the `contentview`. But it gives me error (`CALayer` require its own layer tree), basically saying i shouldn't do `contentview.addsubview(self.view)`. So i tried matching the new `viewcontroller's` view to the content view by using constraint, but the constraint failed and it doesn't show the tab-bar anymore. Any idea on how to do this, possibly elegantly from the `baseviewcontroller`?

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController, SlideMenuDelegate, SwitchTabBarDelegate{

//some other ui,custom nav and controls stuff

private var switchTabBar : SwitchTabBar!
var contentView : UIView!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.configureNavBar()
    self.configureScreenEdgeRecognizer()
    self.configureBaseView()
}

private func configureBaseView(){
        //set up contentView for future View to add into
        self.contentView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.view.addSubview(contentView)
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

        //set up switchtabbar for switching between viewcontrollers that inherit from base viewcontroller
        self.switchTabBar = SwitchTabBar(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.switchTabBar.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(switchTabBar)
        self.switchTabBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.contentView!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.switchTabBar!, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.switchTabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        self.switchTabBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.switchTabBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        self.switchTabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.bounds.size.height/10).isActive = true
    }

// some other ui functions and controls + delegate method
}

class MainPageViewController: BaseViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contentView.addsubview(self.view) //gives error
        //or
        self.view.frame = contentView.frame //doesn't work
        //or
        self.view.frame = contentView.bounds //doesn't work
        self.view.topAnchor.constraint(contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
         /* lead,trail,bottom constraint etc but constraint breaks onruntime and won't show tab-bar anymore */
    }

    //edit: tried new method
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews(){
         super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
         // this create half black screen so still doesn't work
         self.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds //think because contentView is constraint to the actual view it doesn't work.
    }

}
```

Note that `BaseViewController` doesn't have a `.xib` or is present in `storyboard` and it's entirely by code, but the subsequent `viewcontroller` can and will be on the `storyboard` with outlets and such so my designer can change how it looks.

After Edit: from this experiment, it seems like the `BaseViewController` 's view and inherit-class's view is the one and the same, judging from the half black screen i got when i try putting in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Guess for now i'll just build the design around the bottom tab-bar by adding an empty view with clear color in the storyboard and building around it then.

Comment: there is no other way than setting up your views around that bar on bottom, you can't create view controller and hide it inside it's own view. It is like you would want to hide in your own pocket

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting frame try with bounds in the child view controller like: `self.view.frame = contentView.bounds`.

also remove the line `contentView.addsubview(self.view)` because the view is already a part of view hierarchy

So your child view controller's didLoad method may look like:

```
class MainPageViewController: BaseViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.frame = contentView.bounds //doesn't work
    }

}
```

hope it helps..!!!

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried adding debug message to help me understand but apparently, since i initiated the content view with cgRect.zero, the height is zero, after i followed your method and set it, the view frame height is also set to zero, then immediately go back to its original height

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've got it. After trying different approach, i found one that do the trick sort of but not very elegant.

I've removed my `contentView` from my `BaseViewController`,in my inherit-class `MainPageViewController` storyboard, i add a view, call it `contentView` and make it auto-layout to the safe-area, but i grab the bottomConstraint and have an outlet of it in the viewController.
Then i remove it on run time, then add a connecting constraint of `contentView`'s bottom to `switchTabBar`'s top and voila.

```
class MainViewController: BaseViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var newContentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var newContentBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpView()
    }

    private func setUpView(){
        self.newContentBottomConstraint.isActive = false
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.newContentView!, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.switchTabBar!, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    }

}
```

So now i just need to first add "contentView" on future `viewController` classes and do all the design in the "contentView", sort of like how you do `scrollView` with the contentView. This answer is not very elegant but it gets the job done i guess. If anybody else have a better solution, please post so maybe i can change accordingly if its not too much trouble